# AJAX Request on change function with jQuery/Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to get a rails partial when a select input value changes. The goal is to populate the empty select input with options that are located in a partial.

Right now, console is saying `GET http://localhost:3000/occupation 404 (Not Found)`

HTML

```
<select class="occupation-primary">
    <option value="1">Occupation 1</option>
    <option value="2">Occupation 2</option>
</select>

<select id="occupation-secondary">

</select>
```

JS

```
$('.occupation-primary').change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "occupation",
        type: "GET",
    })
});
```

questionnaires_controller.rb

```
def occupation
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
    end
end
```

questionnaires/occupation.js.erb

```
$('#occupation-secondary').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(partial: 'questionnaires/options')).html_safe %>");
```

questionnaires/_options.html.erb

```
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
<option value="2">Option 2</option>
```

routes.rb

```
get "questionnaires/occupation" => "questionnaires#occupation", as: :occupation
```

Comment: You need to use the following URL: `url: "/questionnaires/occupation",`

Comment: When I try that I get: the server responded with a status of 404 http://localhost:3000/questionnaires/questionnaires/occupation

Comment: Sorry I edited my comment, I forgot a "/"

Comment: Similar error this time: the server responded with a status of 404 localhost:3000/questionnaires/occupation

Comment: try to change this: get "questionnaires/occupation" => "questionnaires#occupation", as: :occupation
to this: get "questionnaires/occupation" => "questionnaires#occupation", as: 'occupation'
and test the get again

Comment: Now it says: GET http://localhost:3000/questionnaires/occupation 404 (Not Found) and points to an error in jQuery file, jquery.js?body=1:9667

Comment: add this to your ajax call:
dataType: 'script'

Comment: That returns an error saying: The action 'show' could not be found for QuestionnairesController. But I don't have/need a show action as far as I know?

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. Try to copy / paste on a browser tab this: http://localhost:3000/questionnaires/occupation. Does it get something?

Comment: It says The action 'show' could not be found for QuestionnairesController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this in your routes rb, to bypass the "show" error:

```
get "questionnaire/occupation" => "questionnaires#occupation", as: :occupation #skip the 's'
```

And it will work without the "s"

```
http://localhost:3000/questionnaire/occupation
```

Otherwise, if your are using

```
resources :questionnaires
```

in routes rb, you need to say :except => :show

```
resources :questionnaires, :except => :show
```

Don't forget to change the url in the ajax call, to "questionnaire/occupation" or "questionnaires/occupation", depending on what you chose to do.

Comment: I added except => show to the routes. I left the 's' in though and it's working now.